# How can a function find a parent element of the anchor which originally called the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parent, tree-traversal

Ok, the question alone is making my head spin.

I have an anchor tag that is calling a function:

```
<a href="#" id="addPerson" onClick="addPerson(); return false;">Add a Guest</a>
```

Just for reference, this is the function that's being called:

```
function addPerson() {
//current keeps track of how many rows we have.
current++;
console.log($(this).parent('form').attr('id'));
var strToAdd = '<div class="row">\
          <div class="column grid_2">\
            <label for="two-guests-name'+current+'">Guest '+current+':</label>\
          </div>\
          <div class="column grid_5">\
            <input name="two-guests-name'+current+'" type="text" id="two-guests-name'+current+'" value="Name" onfocus="RemoveFormatString(this, \'Name\')" /> \
            <input name="two-guests-age'+current+'" type="text" class="guestage digits" id="two-guests-age'+current+'" value="Age" size="4" maxlength="3" onfocus="RemoveFormatString(this, \'Age\')" />\
          </div>\
        </div>'

$('#numberguests').append(strToAdd)
};
```

I'd like to allow this function to work on multiple forms on a single page. So my thinking was to travel back in the tree to the parent form element, get its id and use that (somehow) to allow the function to work on multiple forms in the page.

You can see I tried using a quick console.log to test my idea, but it kept coming back "Undefined". I also tried running the console.log in the anchor tag itself, but it also was "Undefined".

I tested .parents() and it works perfectly in the anchor tag, but not in the function iteslf.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass $(this) into add parents and then you'll have the proper scope to work with in your function. So:

```
<a href="#" id="addPerson" onClick="addPerson($(this)); return false;">Add a Guest</a>
```

and then in the function use:

```
function addPerson(anchorElement) {
    var form = anchorElement.parents("form");
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: Why you pass `$(this)` in as an argument when you can just bind the context directly with `.call(this)`?

Comment: Either way works, and your way is probably more elegant. But at some stage you need to wrap "this" as a jquery object with $() in order to use parents() etc. Ideally we'd bind the event in the js and not even use the onclick in the html at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `onclick` attribute use jQuery event binding. As you didn't provide any info about the markup you need to fill in the selector yourself

```
//this binds the same function to all a tags specified by the selector
$("form somemoreselectorgotgettheright a").bind("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).parent("form").attr("id"));
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` context is different. Change the onclick to this:

```
addPerson.call(this);
```

That will make the `this` in the function match up with the `this` in the anchor tag.

Or better yet, don't use an onclick attribute at all, but use a jQuery event handler attachment, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addPerson').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        // Do something with $(this), which is the anchor tag
    });
});
```

And your anchor tag would not have any click handler on it:

```
<a href="#" id="addPerson">Add a Guest</a>
```

Comment: Does ev.preventDefault() act as a return false?

Comment: @Fireflight, for your purposes, yes. But technically, the answer is only sort of. `ev.preventDefault()` stops the default action -- so for a link, it will stop the browser from going to the next page (which is good for your case). For a submit button, it will stop the browser from submitting the form. Whatever the normal browser action is, `preventDefault` stops it.

Comment: But actions also bubble up and affect all containing elements. So if you click on a link, the containing div, and its container, all the way up to the body and html tags -- they all receive a "click" event as well. Most of these click events don't mean anything (think about randomly clicking on a text part of a webpage -- it does nothing). BUt technically, it is still receiving the event. `ev.stopPropagation()` stops the event from bubbling up to containing elements. Anyway, `return false` is a shorthand for doing both `ev.preventDefault()` and `ev.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: I prefer explicitly doing `ev.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` for three reasons: (1) It's clear what it's doing. The name itself "preventDefault" says it. (2) You can put it anywhere in the function call and continue doing the rest of the function (notice I put as the first line in my example) -- this gives you more freedom of structure. (3) The "return" directive has a specific semantic meaning of returning a value back to the function caller. Returning 'false' in an event handler doesn't respect that semantic meaning -- it as almost an abuse of the intention of 'return'.

Answer (score 0):

Use parents() with a selector (this will search upward through all parents until the match i found). e.g.

```
$(this).parents('form').[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the id as a parameter. Eg

```
<a href="#" id="addPerson" onClick="addPerson('addPerson'); return false;">Add a Guest</a>

then...

function addPerson(parent_id) {
// do something with parent_id
```