# Javascript function to send parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please tell me how to send div id as a parameter to **javascript** function onclick in a link of a page to open it via **javascript**. I want to send div id to open that particular link.

```
<a id="anchor22" href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/%C3%98strig" onclick="MyFunction()>Ostrig</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function MyFunction(anchor) {
        document.getElementById('achor').click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your code you have tried so far?

Comment: <div id="div1" style="display:none">
                        <a id="anchor1" href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Belgien">Belgium</a>
                        <a id="anchor2" href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Bulgarien">Bulgarien</a>

Comment: script type="text/javascript">
                     function MyFunction(anchor) {
                         document.getElementById('achor').click();
                    }
                </script>

Comment: Please edit your post instead of adding your code in comments, this is unreadable.

Comment: you want to send `id` of `<a>` to the JS function? or the `id` of `div`

Comment: Anchors can't be opened by triggering click.

Comment: Your script uses #anchor. Where is #anchor?

Comment: Use `addEventListener`, and to open links you have to do `window.location = anchor.href` etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a function find a parent element of the anchor which originally called the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250669/how-can-a-function-find-a-parent-element-of-the-anchor-which-originally-called-t)

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer consider selecting answer as best answer if you find any otherwise provide your persisting problem in detail..

Answer (score 1):

Use this way -

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  document.getElementById('showId').innerHTML = x.parentElement.id; // x.parentElement.id gets the parent div then its id value
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <a href="#" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Me</a> <!-- pass this to the function -->
</div>
<br />Div's id: <span id="showId">
</span>
```

The above code was just for simplicity. For your sample code -

```
<div id="div1">
<a id="anchor22" href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/%C3%98strig" onclick="MyFunction(this)>Ostrig</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function MyFunction(anchor) {
      alert(anchor.parentElement.id); // Will return div1
      alert(anchor.id); // Will return anchor22
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Would you surmise what you think the question is?

Comment: the question was to pass the `id` of `div` to the `MyFunction()` that's it.

Comment: Makes sense when you put it like that.